# Docker writing to server mounted volume, permission issue

Tags: docker, permissions, volume, docker-volume, userid

I have been having permission issues with mounted volumes on my docker container that is on a server. I have made sure that the user and group ID are the same, but I am still having issues.

Any help on this would be appreciated, new docker user here.

IDs outside of the container, just on the file system:

```
[millebri@exahead1 lifted_over]$ id
uid=5507(millebri) gid=2069(ConradLab) groups=2069(ConradLab),2084(primeseqreader),3010(HPCUsers),3759(accessexacloud),3777(docker),3984(accessmonkeydo),5507(millebri)
```

Folder IDs outside of the container:

```
[millebri@exahead1 data]$ ls -hal
drwxr-sr-x  7 millebri ConradLab  286 Jun 29 19:31 twins_UK
```

Running the container (interactively this time):

```
sudo /opt/acc/sbin/exadocker run \
    -i \
    -t \
    --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    --rm \
    -v /home/groups/ConradLab:/ConradLab \
    millebri/variant_calling_pipeline:latest
```

IDs inside of the container:

```
I have no name!@b66ad0ea727d:/home/newuser$ id
uid=5507 gid=2069 groups=2069
```

Folder IDs inside of the container:

```
I have no name!@b1e3af15d2e1:/ConradLab/data$ ls -hal
drwxr-sr-x  7 5507 2069  286 Jun 30 02:31 twins_UK
```

Error message returned (line 22 is where I make a file and write it to the volume)

```
vcf_to_bed.sh: line 22: EGAF00000498465_hg38liftover_snv_tmp.bed: Permission denied
```

Any help would be appreciated.

With all of that said the underlying issue may be that the root of the folder that I am looking to write to is owned by root, but i'm pretty sure this is irrelevant.

```
[millebri@exanode-2-44 groups]$ ls -hal
drwxrws--x 18 root   ConradLab     398 Jun 25 13:41 ConradLab
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that includes a shell script to generate the error? Is SELinux enabled on the host?